# What sort of order of magnitude in time does it take from code like GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.LOW) to be executed to led being lighted up?

Tags: gpio, python, electronics

So I am lighting up an through hole led using 5V and an GPIO pin. I have code in python and I’m trying to get a precise timestamp of when the LED lights up with something like this:

```
GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.low)
Led_timestamp = Time.time_ns()
```

What sort of accuracy can I expect from the timestamp? Millisecond? Microseconds?

Comment: buy a cheap `logic analyzer` to view the output of the GPIO pin ... use inline code without loops ... repeat these two line about 100 times `GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.low)` `GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.high)` ... loop the 200 lines for continuous output ... view the result

Comment: another thing to try, save a timestamp, run `GPIO.output(led_pin, GPIO.low)` 100 times, save another timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This is guesswork.  For accurate figures you will have to conduct your own experiments.

I'd expect of the order of ten thousand toggles per second from Python.  Each toggle would be on then off.  So each GPIO write would be of the order of 50µs.

Generally the timestamp will be made just after the GPIO write.  For the sake of argument assume a latency of another 50µs.

However occasionally there will be a reschedule between the GPIO write and the timestamp call in which case the latency might be tens of milliseconds.